Understanding the role of independence in concentration inequalities
I’ve been reading about concentration inequalities, and I came across McDiarmid’s inequality. The theorem states that if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are independent random variables and $f(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition, so that, for any $i$ and any values $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and $y_i$,
$$
|f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n) - f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{i-1}, y_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)| \leq c
$$ then the deviation of $f(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ from its expected value can be bounded.
As I was reading through the proof, I found that the independence of the random variables is used only once. Specifically, in this step:
$$
\mathbb{E}[f_i(\vec{X}, x) - f_i(\vec{X}, y) \mid X_1 = z_1, \ldots, X_{i-1} = z_{i-1}] 
= \\
\sum_{z_{i+1}, \ldots, z_n} \Pr((X_{i+1} = z_{i+1}) \cap \cdots \cap (X_n = z_n)) \cdot (f_i(\vec{z}, x) - f_i(\vec{z}, y)),
$$
from here bounding the difference by the Lipschitz constant $c$ and using $\sum \Pr((X_{i+1} = z_{i+1}) \cap \cdots \cap (X_n = z_n)) = 1$ are key steps for upper bounding the above mean with $c$.
I would like to understand why independence is necessary. Specifically, I am looking for a counterexample where the $X_i$ are dependent, and the lack of independence causes:
$$
\left| \mathbb{E}[f(X_1, \dots, X_n) \mid X_1, \dots, X_i] - \mathbb{E}[f(X_1, \dots, X_n) \mid X_1, \dots, X_{i-1}] \right| > c.
$$
This would mean that the probabilities in the summation exceed 1, breaking the proof of McDiarmid’s inequality.
Can someone provide an example of dependent random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ that demonstrate this failure? Specifically, how does dependency lead to this breakdown?

Looking at the proof on Wikipedia, I think that independence is used a couple of steps before applying Azuma's inequality. Also, Azuma's inequality itself does not assume independence, although I am not experienced with these inequalities, so I might be wrong.
Regarding your example, for
$
\mathbb{E}[f(X, 1) - f(X, 0)] = \sum_{x=0,1} \Pr(X=x) \cdot (f(x, 1) - f(x, 0)) = 1 \leq 1 = c,
$
it seems that the bound holds here and does not break the inequality I mentioned above. However, it is possible that I am not completely understanding what you proposed.

@(Robert Israel) why did you delete your comment it took me time to answer you properly? Why remove the context?

Firstly, just to be clear that some independence type assumption is required, suppose that all the $X \in \{+1, -1\}$, and that if $X_1 = 1,$ then all the other $X$s are all $1$ surely, while if $X_1 = -1,$ then all the other $X_j$s are independent and uniform. With this structure, consider the map $f(x_1^n) = \sum x_i/n,$ which is $1/n$-Lipschitz. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(X_1^n)] = 1/2  -1/2n,$ but clearly $f = 1$ with probability $1/2,$ and $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ with probability $1/2$, so we're not seeing concentration of the value of $f$ in the sense of MacDiarmid's inequality (which would suggest concentration at the scale $1/\sqrt{n}$).
To dive deeper, of course, MacDiarmid is using Azuma with the MDS $Z_j = \mathbb{E}[f(X_1^n)|X_1^j] - \mathbb{E}[f(X_1^n)|X_1^{j-1}],$ and the core argument establishes boundedness of these $Z_j$s.  Clearly, then, the issue has to be that if we don't supply enough independence, some of the $Z_j$s can be untenably large (the above example shows that $Z_1$ can vary at the scale $1$, for instance).
In detail,  observe that $$ \mathbb{E}[ f(X_1^n)|X_1^j = x_1^j] = \sum_{X_{j+1}^n} f(x_1^{j-1}, x_j, X_{j+1}^n) P(X_{j+1}^n|X_1^{j} = x_1^{j}).$$
On the other hand, $$ \mathbb{E}[f(X_1^n)|X_1^{j-1} = x_1^{j-1}] = \sum_{X_{j}^n} f(x_1^{j-1}, X_j, X_{j+1}^n) P(X_j^n|X_1^{j-1} = x_1^{j-1})\\
= \sum_{X_{j+1}^n} \sum_{X_j} f(x_1^{j-1}, X_j, X_{j+1}^n) P(X_j|X_1^{j-1} = x_1^{j-1}) \cdot P(X_{j+1}^n|X_1^{j-1} = x_1^{j-1}, X_j )  .$$
The problem now is that the measures being integrated with respect to are distinct, so it's hard to control difference. The main headache is that $P(X_{j+1}^n|x_1^{j-1}, X_j)$ can vary significantly with $X_j$, and due to this, even under lipschitzness, we might end up integrating to very different values. In the example I gave, this was quite extreme (for $j = 1,$ with one value of $X_1,$ all the $X_j$s concentrated on $1$, while with the other, they were super spread out).
Independence, of course, ensures that the above does not happen, since in this case $P(X_{j+1}^n|x_1^{j-1}, X_j)$ doesn't vary with $X_j$ at all. In principle, you can replace this independence with some milder condition: for instance, maybe the $X_{j+1}^n$ mix pretty well, so that the distribution of $X_{j + \kappa}^n$ is essentially independent of the value of $X_j$ (and then you can pull out some bound on $Z_j$ linear in $\kappa$). Such mixing type conditions are common when studying dependent data, you can perhaps look at some work on time series et c.
